# Retrieve child nodes Firebase Database Android into separate variables?

Tags: java, android

Retrieve child nodes into separate variables from Firebase Database Android.

Screenshot of my database [image]

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myNewRef = database.getReference("F-5/Islamabad Marriott Hotel");

myNewRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          public String FastFood;
          public String Desi;
          public String Continental;

          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

              if(dataSnapshot.child("Continental")!= null){
                 Continental = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                 cityTextOne.setText(Continental);
              }
              if(dataSnapshot.child("Desi")!= null){
                  Desi = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                  cityTextTwo.setText(Desi);
              }
              if(dataSnapshot.child("Fast-Food")!= null){
                  FastFood = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                  cityTextThree.setText(FastFood);
              }
          }
});
```

But somehow I cannot retrieve and store the values. Need Help?

Comment: you can follow this answer to get data from firebase :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55872600/get-data-from-firebase-realtime-between-table-to-recycler-view/55877145#55877145

Answer (score 0):

Try getKey() instead of child().

```
          if(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("Continental")){
             Continental = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
             cityTextOne.setText(Continental);
          }
```